# Where to start for solve this exercise in c

Tags: c, set

Hello I resort to your help with the intention of indicating me, what are the steps that I must follow to solve this exercise make it clear that I am not asking for the solution to the problem

Given a set {1...N} We can divide it into two subsets that their sum give the same, for example for N = 3:

```
{1,2} = {3}
```

Another example with N = 7:

```
{1,6,7} = {2,3,4,5}
{2,5,7} = {1,3,4,6}
{3,4,7} = {1,2,5,6}
{1,2,4,7} = {3,5,6}
```

Given an N, calculate how many ways we can make the subsets for this property is fulfilled, for N = 3 we have seen that there is a possibility; for N = 7 we have 4 possibilities. Make a recursive algorithm that solves for any 0 < N < 39.

```
Example input:
7
The function must be given:
3
Example input 2:
3
Example output 2
1
```

any aid would be welcome

**edit**

```
#include<stdio.h>

int count( int S[], int m, int n )
{
     if (n == 0)
       return 1;


    if (n < 0)
        return 0;
    if (m <=0 && n >= 1)
        return 0;
    return count( S, m - 1, n ) + count( S, m, n-S[m-1] );
}
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,2};
    int m = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    printf("%d ", count(arr, m, 3));

    return 0;
}
```

in this case two gives me instead of one it's wrong

Comment: Your base case is N=3. To get the recursive case, you must figure out what happens when you go from N=k to N=(k+1)

Comment: What topics have your lectures covered on algorithms?  Dynamic algorithms, backtracking, recursion (presumably), …?  Clearly, when the sum of {1..N} is an odd number, there's no point in trying to continue (so N ∈ { 1, 2, 5, 6, … } will never have a solution).  How can you build up the result?  How can you determine when there is no point in continuing further? (Hint, if the number in the LH set add up to more than half the maximum, there's no way for the the RH set to equal it; equally, if the the LH set equals half the sum, everything that's left over must match it.)

Comment: you don't need arr because the structure of your array is well known (you know they go from 1 to N

Comment: the code is correct, the only problem is that 
{1,2} = {3} and
{3} = {1,2} are considered two different correct solutions. you need to divide it by 2 if you want the number of "unique" solution. (don't forget to check n*(n+1)/2 is an even number, if it is not the case then you don't have any solution)

Comment: friend I missed here, as I'm supposed to do without the array, please you can modify the code proposed any way you deems appropriate i carry two days with this exercise, already I get tired

Answer (score 1):

You could use the fact that the sum of the values is n*(n+1)/2. Your task is to find all the sets with n*(n+1)/4. to do this you can use the change-making algorithm (it is recursive as your require). Your coins are the integers for 1 to N and the money you want to distribute is n*(n+1)/4.

Source : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem

Comment: edit my question with the solution that believes you can tell me if this is good